Accessing Children of USDZ Model in SwiftUI
I'm developing a visionOS app using SwiftUI and RealityKit. I'm facing a challenge with accessing the children of a USDZ model.
Scenario
I can successfully load and display a USDZ model in my RealityView.
When I import the model into Reality Composer Pro, I can access and manipulate its individual parts (children) using the scene hierarchy.
However, if I directly load the USDZ model from the Navigation tab in my project, I cannot seem to access the children programmatically.
Question
Is there a way to access and manipulate the children of a USDZ model loaded directly from the Navigation tab in SwiftUI for visionOS?
Additional Information
I've explored using an entity (named: "childName", in: realityKitContentBundle), but this only works for the main entity.
I'm open to alternative approaches if directly accessing children isn't feasible.

Please share your model via file sharing service. I'll show you how to do it programmatically.
